# Core Data & Many-to-Many

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

I've got an iOS app working very well with two Core Data entities: Employee and Department.
I have one UITableViewController that's an NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate that displays Employees and data about them and another that displays Departments and data about them.

I'm having a hard time understanding how I *add* relationships, though.
I understand how to *create* relationships (using the graph view of the data model), but I can't seem to find any good information about adding the actual relationships.

In a standard SQL db I would have a cross-reference table with columns for DepartmentID and EmployeeID to link them. But that doesn't seem to be appropriate with Core Data.

How does one add entity relationships in Swift?

Comment: For clarification, if you have an "HR" department and an employee "Bob", you're asking how to add "Bob" to the "HR" department (with the inverse of "HR" adding "Bob" as well)?

Comment: @ghostatron Yes, exactly.

(And then, of course, how to find all the employees in HR and all the departments with which Bob is associated.)

Comment: I hate it, but the only way I have found is something like: employeeBob.mutableSetValue(forKey: "departments").add(hrDepartment).  That should handle updating the inverse for you. Then, later, you can call employeeBob.departments to get a set that has hrDepartment.

Comment: @ghostatron In that example, I assume the forKey value is the name of the relationship from my data model. But what is the hrDepartment in the add()? Would I use the DepartmentID or the DepartmentTitle or what? How do it know?

Comment: Correct, the key is the name of the relationship.  The hrDepartment is an actual Department NSManagedObject instance.

Comment: @ghostatron:

1. That did it! Can you add your reply as an answer so I can mark it correct?

2. I'm doing this in a loop while grabbing new items from an API. How can I prevent adding Bob to the HR department every time the process runs? IOW: I don't want to add the relationship if it already exists.

Comment: You could check using another query, but that's expensive if you are looping thousands of items. What I would probably do, is maintain a lookup of my own: maybe 2 dictionaries, one with EmployeeID as the key and a set of DepartmentId strings as the value, and the other with DepartmentId as the key and a set of EmployeeIds as the value. Query/Update those as you go through your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of mutableSetValue by doing something similar to this snippet:

```
let employeeBob: Employee = ...
let departmentHR: Department = ...
employeeBob.mutableSetValue(forKey: "departments").add(departmentHR)
```

Afterwards, you can access Bob's departments by requesting employeeBob.departments, or you can get the employees in HR by requesting departmentHR.employees. (i.e. that snippet handles the inverse for you as well.)

If you want to check if Bob is already in HR, then you can check if departmentHR.employees.contains(employeeBob).  HOWEVER, be careful because it does that check by reference (not employee ID or whatever)...That is, if you create Bob twice (2 different NSManagedObjects with different NSManagedObjectId), then they won't "match".  That said, since it is a set, if you know Bob is Bob (like, every time you see Bob, it's the same Bob object/reference), then you can add him over and over and the set will automatically protect you from dupes.